# Swagger UI outputs "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I use **Swashbuckle 5.0.0** and **.NET Core 3.0**. When I run the solution from Visual Studio and I test the API `http://localhost:52969/api/Token/GetToken`, I get the error:

[image]

This is the code of my controller:

```
namespace cc.Api.TokenHandler.Controllers {

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class TokenController : ControllerBase {

        private readonly Auth0TokenHandler _authorizationHandler;

        public TokenController(IPersistToken persistToken) {
            _authorizationHandler = new Auth0TokenHandler(persistToken);
        }

        [HttpGet("GetToken")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(RequestTokenModel), 200)]
        public async Task<RequestTokenModel> GetToken([FromBody]TokenParams tokenParams) {
            _authorizationHandler.Domain = tokenParams.Domain;
            _authorizationHandler.Audience = tokenParams.Audience;
            _authorizationHandler.ClientId = tokenParams.Client;
            _authorizationHandler.ClientSecret = tokenParams.ClientSecret;
            return await _authorizationHandler.GetTokenModel();
        }

        [HttpGet("GetAccessToken")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 200)]
        public async Task<string> GetAccessToken([FromBody]TokenParams tokenParams) {
            return (await GetToken(tokenParams))?.AccessToken;
        }

    }

}
```

Why do I get the error?

Comment: Could it be that the method returns a string, instead of the json, like you did declare on the controller level? just a guess tbh

Comment: @Isparia the method returns a `RequestTokenModel`, with the `Task` and `async` stuff.

Comment: Ahh sry my bad, i just saw the last action, which in turn executes the get token action. But this still could lead to the error. Can you just for the test comment out the `getaccesstoken` action and try again, it might be that the filter on the controller has the problem and not the action itself.

Comment: Since `GetToken` and `GetAccessToken` use `[FromBody]` parameters, should their request method be POST instead of GET? GET operations are not supposed to have a body (the body in GET doesn't have defined semantics).

Comment: You’re right, but the issue is that it should be a `GET` since I need to retrieve something. I thought I needed to use the `[FromUri]` attribute, but it doesn’t recognize it, and I don’t understand how to make it available.

Comment: You don't need `[FromBody]` when you have `[ApiController]` attribute. Try to remove   `[ApiController]`  and use `[FromQuery]` instead